# How to Hash Buffer with Expo. Crypto. digestStringAsync()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/crypto/
Info: **app is in react-native & Expo**

Expo now provides a hashing method but only accepts String types for input.

**Nodejs** provides hashing of `buffers/strings/arrays` and can `return` the **hashed value as a buffer as well**.

The issue I am having is that I need to hash a buffer(`uint8array`) in my app with **sha256**. So I must find a way to convert it to a string, this causes issues because if I convert the buffer to anything else ex.(`hexString,base64`) my hash result is not equivalent to the exact value that **nodejs crypto** would provide.

I have also tried converting the buffer to `utf-8/16 strings` but this causes issues because the `chars` in this format can have multiple bytes(**issues with the number being above 127**). So this path was incorrect as well.

My hashes must be equivalent to the traditional **nodejs** `createHash()` results.

I am hitting a wall on this issue and not not find a way around it.

Comment: Uint8Array are not Buffer objects per say: have you tried using the `buffer` npm module to polyfill the missing Buffer definition in expo ? I had a slightly different problem than yours, but this polyfill solved my problem. I'm not sure that would solve your problem in your case though.

Comment: I am having the same problem as well, for added information. I tried the digestStringAsync(.., {encoding: 'hex'} this only drives the return type. If the return type is a HEX string, the side effect is that chaining will not be possible either.